# How Do I Connect to a Neo4J AuraDB Instance from R Studio

Tags: r, neo4j, neo4j-aura

I created a Neo4j AuraDB database where I have dumped the movie recommendation dataset. I am able to start and connect to the instance in the cloud. However, when I try to connect to the instance via its API in R Studio, using the `neo4r` package and the following code

```
movieDB <- neo4j_api$new(
  url = curl("neo4j+s://0cc45a14.production-orch-0054.neo4j.io:7687"),
  user = "neo4j",
  password = "password"
)

movieDB$ping()
```

I get the error message in my console `Error: Could not resolve host: 7`. Also, when I try to start a graph with the following code

```
graph <- startGraph(
  url = curl("neo4j+s://0cc45a14.production-orch-0054.neo4j.io:7687"),
  user = "neo4j",
  password = "password"
)
```

I also get the following error message in my console

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: 8
```

I do not know why the error is happening, as I have previously connected to a Neo4j sandbox instance from within R Studio without any hassle. As always, I will appreciate your helpful suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AuraDB requires a driver which supports the Bolt protocol. I do not know of any R driver that supports the protocol at the moment, they only support HTTP (and HTTP is not available yet in AuraDB).

Comment: I am trying to connect via http calls. Is it supported as of now?